# jQuery draggable: limiting drag for an irregular area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an image-based map. I want to drag a div within a specified area of the map. Is it possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is useful info:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/